# How can i make sure that different end users keep their files/program state to themselves while accessing my program simultaneously in PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, user-accounts, file-management

I currently have a program on PythonAnywhere. The program involves a user uploading files and then these files are analyzed. How can I make sure that if one person is logged into the program on their computer, someone logging into the program from a different computer wont change the data of person a's program. How should I got about managing this? Ideally my program would have an account manager that loads the file based on logged in user. In terms of storing the separate files, I was just going to send them into a directory named after the username.

Comment: You'll probably want to look at using some sort of secure session cookie to identify users and then have some sort of permissions table that contains information about what they are allowed to see. Most frameworks have some sort of session support - check the docs of the framework you're using.

Comment: Thank you @Glenn ! That was very helpful and definitely a step in the right direction for me. Anything else you would recommend checking out?  I know the server setup isnt exactly the clearest